# List of element type of $(e.target).is();

Tags: jquery

Is there a list anywhere, where I can see the `$(e.target).is(xxx)` xxx parameters.

I asked this, because I need to check, if a user clicks on a table row, the clicked item was a link or not.

I looked for it, and found [this](https://coderwall.com/p/mew6tg/how-to-check-the-element-type-of-an-event-target-with-jquery).

After this, I've checked the jQuery documentation of [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

So, for me it was logical to use this:

```
`$(e.target).is(':a')`
```

and I've got this error message:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: a

I've just gave a shot to `:link` what has worked.

Comment: It supports most [CSS3 selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) and a [fair few others](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Don't make up selectors without checking selectors api is the short answer. Tag names are pretty simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:a` isn't a valid selector. You should simply use `a`:

```
$(e.target).is('a')
```

`.is()` accepts valid CSS selectors, jQuery-specific selectors, elements, or jQuery objects.

Comment: last statement isn't entirely accurate since jQuery also has pseudo selectors that also work like ... `:animated` or `:visible` or `:checkbox`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.is()` method works with CSS selectors. There's a list of selectors supported out-of-the-box on the [jQuery Website](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), although [jQuery can be extended to support other selectors](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/extending-jquerys-selector-capabilities/).

Answer (score 0):

you don't need jQuery, you could just do something like

```
if (e.target.hasAttribute('href')) {
//dothis
}
```